# LibGDX - How to make a touchable image?

Tags: events, click, touch, libgdx

so I'm developing a game for android in LibGDX and I've stumbled upon a problem: I have a scene with an image in it and I want to be able to click/touch the image and make stuff happen after doing so.
I've been trying to google a solution for the past day but I keep on missing something vital. Here's my code:

```
public class ScreenSplash implements Screen {

    private Texture textureGlobe = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("graphics/splash.png"));
    private Image imageGlobe = new Image((new TextureRegion(textureGlobe)));

    public ScreenSplash() {

        imageGlobe.addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                Gdx.app.log(Game.LOG, "image clicked");
                return true;
            }
        });
        stageGame.addActor(imageGlobe);
    }

    ...

}
```

I've also heard that I'm supposed to put this somewhere:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
```

But I don't really know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I've found out what the problem was.

I imported java.awt.event.InputEvent instead of com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent and the touchDown function wasn't properly overriden because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Stage` is your `InputProcessor` so do something like `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stageGame);`. The `Stage` will route the events to the actors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried this before (and I'm trying it again now just to be sure) but it doesn't seem to work. I keep clicking on the image but nothing happens :\

Comment: Please try System.out.println instead. I have noticed that the logging doesn't always work. Furthermore, do you use the very latest nightly build? If that's the case you need to do stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true) in your resize event.

Comment: Perhaps you ment stage.setViewport(width, height, true)? If yes, then I'm already doing it, but it still doesn't work. Neither does the println fix. Wtf?

Comment: Show more code. At this point we don't see your Stage or where you call `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stageGame);`. Do you give your `Image` a height and width? (Usually with `imageGlobe.setBounds`).